# Problema con ionic (angular) y socket.io (express)

Tags: nodejs, angular, ionic, express, socket.io

voy a tratar de ser lo mas especifico posible.

primero un poco de contexto. Estoy iniciando en apps web con una rest-api

la aplicacion web como tal esta hecha con ionic 4 y angular 8 subida en un host de firebase

la aplicacion del servidor esta hecha con express subida en heroku y con una base de datos mysql.

Uso socket.io para que cuando se cargue un dato, en todos los clietnes conectados, el componente de angular que muestra esos datos se actualice con los nuevos, asi la informacion se actualiza en tiempo real

### codigo de socket.io en express

```
this.io.on('connection', (socket : any)=>{
  socket.on("modCompras", () => {
    const compras = sqlCompra.getCompras();
    compras.then( res => {
      this.io.sockets.emit('modCompras', res);
    })
  });
})
```

### codigo del componente que crea la compra

```
addCompra(){
    this.compraService.createCompra(this.newCompra);
    this.newCompra = {precio : "", descripcion : ""};
  }

public createCompra(nuevaCompra : any){
    const http = this.http.post<any>(URL_SERVER+'/api/createCompra', nuevaCompra);
    http.subscribe(
      res => { 
        this.socket.emit('modCompras'); 
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    )
    return http;
  }
```

### codigo del componente que muestra las compras

```
private compras = this.socket.on('modCompras', (data) => { 
    this.items = data; 
});;

public items: any;
```

luego el vector "items" se recorre con un *ngFor y por cada uno se crea una ion-card

El problema radica en que no funciona pero tampoco me salen errores en la consola de javascript del navegador y pasa solo cuando la applicacion esta subida a firebase, si la pruebo de forma local con el servidor de desarrollo de angular, anda correctamente. Pero cuando la uso a travez de firebase, se crean bien las compras pero para que se actualice la informacion tengo que relogear o cerrar y volver a abrir la aplicacion, como si la parte del socket no funcionara.

desde ya muchas gracias y perdon por que quedo un poco largo. Saludos

Comment: Haz comprobado el contenido que tiene tu arreglo de objetos compra en angular desde el frontend cuando lo haces "oficialmente", osea desde la app subida a firebase?, puede que el problema este en que no estes pudiendo recibir los datos de manera correcta cuando intentas usar la app subida a firebase. Comprueba la información que recoges a ver que te pone.

Comment: Por cierto te recomiendo que si usas ionic 4 o superior al valor de la constante http le hagas una pequeña conversión, para ello debes importar el operador map del modulo 'rxjs/operators', luego colocar antes del punto y coma de tu constante un .pipe(map(res => res.json()))); esto te permitira trabajar directamente con la constante en formato json. aquí un ejemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51919181/ionic-this-http-get-map-is-not-a-function

Comment: Eso de arriba solo hazlo si estas usando el modulo Http para hacer el post, de lo contrario si por ejemplo estas usando el modulo HttpClient para hacer la petición esto no será necesario, ya que directamente hace la conversión a json, que por cierto el HttpClient es un modulo "actualizado" y mejorado de http, considera pasarte a el si es posible, aparte este ultimo no necesita que le pases cabeceras de seguridad y opciones para poder funcionar.

Comment: Por cierto, de que manera escuchas la información traida de los eventos que se disparan de node desde el front y con que plugin?

Comment: Por cierto no veo que desde el frontend estes emitiendo alguna data al backend, es decir, cuando tu haces this.socket.emit('modCompras'); lo que haces es emitir el evento pero sin valores, se te habra olvidado ese pequeño detalle imagino...

Comment: que tal, gracias por los comentarios, te cuento.

si comprobe el contenido del arreglo de objetos, el asunto es que este queda vacio puesto que el evento "modCompras" nunca se escucha. Por lo que pude comprobar entiendo que si se llega a emitir desde el front pero en el backend no se que pasa que no se vuelve a emitir.

gracias por los consejos sobre ionic y http los voy a tratar de implementar :)

la informacion la escucho en el codigo del componente que muestra la info, cada vez que alguien crea una compra se emite el evento y el servidor lo reemite y ahi se escucha

Comment: y el tema del evento sin valores es por que el valor lo paso por el post de http, el evento lo emito solo para "avisar" que se modifico, se que mediante el mismo socket puedo mandar la informacion y me ahorro la parte de http, por ahora lo deje asi por que por http mando un token que es para verificar que se este logeado y unas cosas mas, igualmente en un futuro pensaba cambiarlo pero como por el momento no me dio problemas lo deje asi.

Comment: Creo que ese es el problema principal, ya que no es lo mismo hacer una petición por post y enviar la información a un archivo que directamente enviar la información por sockets "las comunicaciones no son iguales ni compatibles" por decirlo así, lo otro es, cargas socket.io desde el cliente desde un script o desde un modulo instalado de nodejs?, puede ser ese otro el problema con ionic, aparte asignas el listener de los eventos de node a una variable privada llamada compras, esto de por si creo que puede darte errores ya que en angular creo que lo que se hace es crear un observable, el cual

Comment: Si lo metes dentro de esa variable solo estara disponible en ese ambiente, tambien habría que escuchar los eventos por medio de una subscripción del observable de io.on desde el front, y dentro de este si le asignas valores a compra. no como tal todo el observable a compras. (Aviso de antemano que si estas cargando el script como si fuera una pagina normal en tu app no te funcionara), debes es instalar un modulo propio para que te funcione con angular.

Comment: Puede ser, voy a cambiar eso entonces para probar, hacer que directametne se mande la informacion por el socket, realmente no estoy del todo seguro que el emmit se llegue a hacer desde el front, creeria que si pero de esa forma terminaria de comprobar si funciona o no, asi que es buena idea. socket.io lo cargo desde el modulo de node "ngx-socket-io". en app.module.ts, lo importo y lo agrego en "imports" el asunto del observable tambien es interesante, entiendo que lo crearia al generar el componente y con la subscripcion escuchar los eventos. la verdad no los manejo del todo pero lo intento :)

Answer (score 0):

Antes que nada, los modulos Http y HttpClient son modulos muy parecidos, solo que digamos que HttpClient es la version mas "actualizada, moderna y segura" de estos modulos, esta se puede usar creo que apartir de angular 7 y ionic 4, así que recomendaria que en vez de usar http, usaras HttpClient:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Luego lo inyectas en el constructor:

```
constructor(public http: HttpClient){}
```

Ahora bien, tienes algo que puede mejorarse en el código, pero antes deberias importar el modulo Observable:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Una vez teniendolo importado tenias la siguiente línea:

```
const http = this.http.post<any>(URL_SERVER+'/api/createCompra', nuevaCompra);
```

Esto lo que te devuelve es un Observable si no estoy mal, lo ideal sería que le especificaras a ionic de que tipo va a ser el valor, en este caso un observable:

```
const http:Observable<any> = this.http.post(URL_SERVER+'/api/createCompra', nuevaCompra);
```

Ahora, como estas usando httpClient directamente te da la data traida del post como un json, por lo que dentro de este puedes hacer operaciones directamente como si fueran un json de js, (fijate que se retorna res y err):

```
http.subscribe(
  res => { 
    this.socket.emit('modCompras', res);
    return res;
  },
  err => throw Exception(err);
)
return http;
```

Ahora, intenta instalar ngx-socket-io en la carpeta raiz del proyecto si tienes ionic4 o superior:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-socket-io

Ahí te mostrara el funcionamiento base de este plugin, este te permite manejar directamente desde angular sockets por parte del cliente en angular usando observables, los cuales son bastante utiles.

Debes leer el ejemplo y adaptarlo para la escucha de eventos desde tu front para poder que esta información cambie de acuerdo a los eventos y la data traida por el backend en nodejs.

Que por cierto, para poder que esto funcione necesitaras usar es el el link junto con el puerto donde se encuentra corriendo tu servidor de nodejs, esta configuración se crea en el app.module y se veria algo así:

```
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://localhost:8988', options: {} };
```

Entonces en vez de poner "http://localhost:8988" colocarias la dirección de tu servidor de node y el puerto correspondiente, y en caso dado de que el servidor rechace la conexión debes permitir los origines desde el backend, pero debes hacerlo con una mayor investigación, hacerlo de la siguiente manera se considera realmente inseguro (debes investigar mas a fondo que restricciones le puedes poner en vez de usar * en Allow-Origin y en origins):

```
const app = require('express')();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  next();
});
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http, {origins: '*:*'});
```

Debes modificar los origenes y los metodos a tu conveniencia, no te puedo dar mas información al respecto ya que desconozco que metodos de origen son fiables o que se podría poner, esto debes investigarlo mas a fondo tu mismo...

De momento lo que podrias hacer para probar si efectivamente sirve, es hacerlo localmente, (crear o copiar el script que tienes subido y usarlo de manera local corriendolo con nodejs) y usando el asterisco en origins, y una vez este a la escucha cambiar tu configuración:

```
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://localhost:8988', options: {} };
```

desde la app a localhost y tu puerto y ver si desde la app funciona (recuerda lo de escuchar con observables), lo que retorna io.on('evento') desde el frontend usando ngx-socket-io es un observable, por lo que debes hacer una subscripción y ya dentro de ella si tratar los valores, puedes hacerlo desde un metodo de la clase y llamarlo desde el constructor y que este se encargue de hacer las subscripciones a los eventos, o directamente hacer las subscripciones a los eventos desde el constructor, (que no creo que sea buena idea ya que queda un poco mas sucio el código).

Por ejemplo, esto es un ejemplo desde una pagina cualquiera.ts en ionic que de hecho es una app en la que estoy trabajando:

```
//Dentro de la clase:
public getConnSubscriber: Subscription;
public connections:Array<any>;

ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.setup();
}

setup(){
    this.setupConnectionSubscriber();
}

setupConnectionSubscriber(){
    this.getConnSubscriber = this.getConnections().subscribe((data:Array<any>) =>{

       /*Esta parte es diferente en mi código y no tengo el array
        *connections, pero igual funcionaria.*/
       this.connections = data;

    }
}

getConnections(){

    let observable = new Observable(observer =>{

      this.socket.on("users-changed", data =>{

        observer.next(data);

      });

    });

    return observable;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tengo un problema con SocketIo y ionic, mi app esta en funcionamiento pero al bloquear el telefono, despues de unos 2 minutos aprox deja de enviar/recibir mensajes, como puedo hacer para que siempre este escuchando mensajes de entrada, como es WhatsApp por ejemplo.

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/393743)